# Connection refused when trying to connect to AWS RDS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm thinking about moving (parts of) my MySQL databases to AWS RDS. They are now running on the same dedicated server as my PHP website but I want to change that for scaling purposes.
So I'm playing around with AWS RDS (I'm new to it). I've setup a MySQL database and **can connect to it using MySQL Workbench**.

The problem is that I can't let my PHP scripts (which are running on a different dedicated Linux server) connect to it using

```
new mysqli('***.***.***.rds.amazonaws.com', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name',3306);
```

I double checked on AWS:

- ... that the DB is Available
- ... the port is 3306
- ... that public accessibility is set to
  'yes'
- ... that both inbound and outbound rules for the security group
  are set to `All traffic - 0.0.0.0/0` and `All traffic - ::/0`

and still PHP is giving me: `mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused`

What am I missing here? Should I change something on the dedicated server too? Note that I'm using the Free tier in AWS while doing these tests.

Comment: Have you checked your local firewall, just in case you are using windows?

Comment: I'm running the PHP scripts on my hosting server, which is CentOS and not on AWS.

Comment: Are the database privileges set to allow connections from your Linux server?

Comment: I found the problem. I had to allow 3306 as outgoing TCP port in my firewall of the dedicated server.